# SQL MAX value of two sub queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two queries and I want to get the maximum value of the two of them.

```
  MAX((SELECT COUNT(p.[ItemID]) FROM [dbo].[Table] p WHERE HasHuman=0),
      (SELECT COUNT(p.[ItemID]) FROM [dbo].[Table] p WHERE HasHuman=1))
```

Comment: UNION ALL in a derived table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate both result in a single query and then apply TOP:

```
select top 1 
   HasHuman,
   COUNT(p.[ItemID]) as cnt
from [dbo].[Table]
group by HasHuman 
order by cnt desc
```

Comment: HasHuman can have values other than 1 and 0, would this work if I added `WHERE HasHuman IN (0,1)`?

Comment: @Nathaniel: Of course, I assumed it was a kind of flag.

Answer (score 2):

You could even do this in a single query:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN HasHuman=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >
              SUM(CASE WHEN HasHuman=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         THEN SUM(CASE WHEN HasHuman=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         ELSE SUM(CASE WHEN HasHuman=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) END
FROM [dbo].[Table]
WHERE ItemID IS NOT NULL    -- you were not counting NULLs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(RC) 
 FROM (SELECT COUNT(p.ItemID) AS RC FROM dbo.[Table]
       WHERE HasHuman=0
       UNION 
       SELECT COUNT(p.ItemID) AS RC FROM dbo.[Table]
       WHERE HasHuman=1
       ) A
```

Comment: Please provide explanations to your answer.